# How to obfuscate Spring Boot App with proguard

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, proguard, obfuscation

I try to obfuscating my spring boot app via proguard maven. Proguard successfully obfuscate jar file. But When I run obfuscate jar file, I got this error;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:45)
```

here is my pom.xml ;

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>proguard</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-pro.jar</outjar>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                </libs>
                <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>
                <options>
                    <option>-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/spring.*</option>
                    <option>-keepattributes
                        Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
                    </option>
                    <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}
                    </option>
                    <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                        @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                        @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                        }
                    </option>
                    <option>-keep class javax.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class org.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class com.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class commons-io.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class commons-codec.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class ommons-collections.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class commons-dbcp.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class cglib.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class postgresql.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class commons-validator.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keep class org.springframework.**</option>
                </options>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I ignored all 3rd party dependencies with ;

```
               <option>-keep class javax.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class org.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class com.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class commons-io.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class commons-codec.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class ommons-collections.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class commons-dbcp.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class cglib.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class postgresql.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class commons-validator.** { *; }</option>
                <option>-keep class org.springframework.**</option>
```

but its not worked.
I also try with proguard.conf but I got same result.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you find the solution because i am using spring-mvc with proguard for Obfuscation but cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add -keep option for all the library jars that you're using. Just keep the main method of your spring boot application and also keep attributes and directory structure. Below conf should work:

```
# Keeps the directory structure intact.
# Spring's @ComponentScan needs the specified directory structure at runtime as well.
-keepdirectories

-keep public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
```